# Node JS - Convert .dat or binary field buffer to .wav file with sox

Tags: node.js, encoding, type-conversion, wav, sox

Programming

I have a question in audio converting I want to convert binary field data buffer to wav or mp3 with programming , but I couldn't find any module for that.

And after make wav file this file is corrupted

Is there a node module for this? I have searched for many hours and didn't find anything helpful.

Anyone please help

Comment: have you tried https://www.npmjs.com/package/ffmpeg? what errors did you face?

Comment: @Yash kumar Verma please give me command for convert .dat to wav in ffmpeg

Comment: have you tried ffmpeg? that can basically convert any format to any other

Comment: @Yash Kumar Verma I want that convert .dat or binary field to .wav how to this ?

Comment: @Yash Kumar Verma ?